# JPA - Mapping a java.util.Stack

Tags: java, jpa, stack

Can I map a [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) to a relational database in JPA?

If I can, will it still have LIFO property after persisting and retrieving?

For example I want to save a history of things in order they happened:

```
class MyEntity {

    Stack<HistoryEntry> history;

}
```

If I can't, can you give me an idea of implementing an ordered-persistent history of things?

Comment: Most JPA providers support most standard Java collections. Why don't you try it? I know DataNucleus JPA supports that one, but others should also

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today.  Basically i found a hacky solution by setting the attribute to List, in the constructor you can pass a Stack, and every time you need the Stack, downcast it with (Stack) list .

Comment: This question was posted a while back. posting now probably wouldn't get much attention.